# Interview data in Python: Count a certain co-occurence separated by speaker

Tags: python, loops, counting, paragraph

This is a social scientist asking. I think I found the first perfect use case (for me) to use Python, but I'm not there yet. I would like to analyze hundreds of formalized interview transcripts, in fact, the basis are protocols of parliamentary debates. It could also be a random interview. I would like to count certain words -- the "cheers" every party gets, ordered by parties --, but as a newcomer to Py I'm struggling to find the correct formula to define the conditions. Simply put, I'm interested in the following research question: *Who is cheering whom?* There are a few "if's" that I would like to be taken care of to produce the desired outcome.

The raw data is complex, but well ordered.

Each discussion is ordered by speaker, who's formally introduced by: "The floor goes to... X". Then there's the speaker's text, there are also blank lines separating the text. When the speaker is finished, the next one is introduced with the same phrase. During the speech members of certain parties "cheer" the speaker, which is indicated in the data bei "(Cheering ... PARTY NAME)." These entries can go over 1 or 2 lines. And I would like to count these "cheers".

Here's an example of the raw data (simplified):

```
The floor goes to member of the parliament Muller by the
Left Party.

Bla bla
bla 
(Cheers Left Party, Green Party, Blue
Party )

Bla

(Cheers Nazi Party) 
Bye Bla

The floor goes to member of the parliament Tsing by the Green Party.

Bla bla
bla 
(Cheers Left Party, Green Party)
```

How do I tell Python to loop through text that follows after a certain string in a certain line (the speaker) has occured? Plus, how do I count co-occurences in a line, thus skipping empty/irrelevant characters (counting the "cheers")? Using a basic word count code I was able to count all the cheers in a file, but that's just a simple start.

```
count = 0
fhand = open('3_parliament.txt') 
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('(Cheers '): continue
    words = line.split()
    count = count + 1
    print(words[1]) 

print("There were", count, "lines in the file with >(Cheers< as the first word")
```

I found additional example code where "paragraphs" were defined, but this does not work here because of the empty lines, and the complex nature of the text in general. textwrapping seemed to produce similar issues. I also find it challenging to count co-occurences in a line ("Cheers ... Party X". Do you have any tipps or hints?

I'm using the latest Python 3.8 on Win 10, via Atom.